# Downloading large videos, what is the best size buffer to have?

Tags: ios, video, memory

I'm making an iOS app that downloads large videos. What is the best size buffer to have in terms of performance. Currently I'm writing 10 megabytes to ram, then flushing it out to disk. With large files this results in a lot of disk writes, but small ram usage. I don't see any poor performance, but I'm just curious what the ideal balance would be. How could I find this out? How expensive is it to write to disk, how frequently should or shouldn't it be done?

Comment: What do mean when you say large videos ? Why don't you prefer to stream those videos via Apple's Http Live Streaming service ?

Comment: A requirement of the app is that they must be downloaded. We are talking videos up to 3gb